# Cookie - Ajax / Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, cookies

I have an ASP.NET 3.5sp1 app that is a single page design. The site never posts back. All interaction is done via ajax. (the site is http://BiblePro.BibleOcean.com)

Anonymous access, no accounts in the app.

I wish to save the user's state so that when they come back it returns to where they left it. Is there a way I can save a cookie to their machine either in javascript or in a call back?

Comment: Is this an advertisement or do you not really know how to use Google to search for "jQuery" and "cookie"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're already using jQuery, see http://plugins.jquery.com/project/cookie

Answer (score 3):

this stuff is [really not hard to find](http://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_cookies.asp) if you know about [google](http://www.google.com/)

Comment: AH, but the quality of answer here is far superior.